# How to smooth/correct sudden exposure changes caused by camera while filming?

Tags: premiere, adobe, time-lapse

I have a video clip which shows clouds in a sunset and it lasts half an hour. During that time the light conditions changed and my camera (Fuji X-e1) tried to compensate the changes of exposure. In the final clip i have sudden exposure changes from time to time. The problem is i want to process the clip as a timelapse which lasts only a few seconds and then the sudden exposure changes appear like a really annoying flicker effect.

I know that there are tools for deflickering a set of photographic images shot for a timelapse clip. But is there also a way to deflicker an already existing videoclip within Adobe premiere?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have AE?
In AE you can use the color stabilizer effect.

Import your project to AE, add the color stabilizer onto the clip, change stabilizer to brightness, qnd choose a point that should be black/really dark

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use Premiere, and don't want to use any other tools (and have lots of time), you could move frame by frame around the areas where you can see exposure jumps, using the Lumetri plugin.

You would add Lumetri to the layer, then set the exposure control to be keyframe-able. Step through frame by frame until you see a jump, then tweak the exposure until it looks better.

It will take a while, and you might get better results with something like [GBDeflicker](http://granitebaysoftware.com/Products/ProductGBD.aspx) though.